# Re-calculate position after rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say I have a UI `Image` like this:

```
+-+     Width = 128
|A|     Height = 640
|B|     Anchors (0,0,0,0)
|C|     Pivot (0,0)
|D|     Rotation (0,0,0)
*-+     Scale (1,1,1)
```

Note the **`*`** is the pivot point, and it's on bottom-left. I want to rotate this UI `Image` with rotation `z = -90.0f`. When I do this I have a box like this:

```
       Width = 128
       Height = 640
       Anchors (0,0,0,0)
       Pivot (0,0)
       Rotation (0,0,-90)
*----+ Scale (1,1,1)
|DCBA|
+----+
```

Note the **`*`** is the pivot point, and not it's not on bottom-left anymore, it's on top-left. Everything is logical from a 3D / maths point of view... but not for the 2D / Pixel guy I am.
I have two problems with that:

- I still have Width=128, Height=640
- The **`*`** = pivot point is on top-left now.

Here's how I'd like the final position to be:

```
       Width = 640
       Height = 128
       Anchors (0,0,0,0)
+----+ Pivot (0,0)
|DCBA| Rotation (0,0,0)
*----+ Scale (1,1,1)
```

It's on the "`click`" event. Here's my code:

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (MenuMain.ModeRotateIsActivated) {
        eventData.pointerPress.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -90f));
        /* maybe use / change rt after that?
        RectTransform boat_rt = 
            eventData.pointerPress.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        */
    }
}
```

What can I could do to modify the object position + pivot like I want?

Comment: You can't get the final result with a rotation, it has to be done on the scale or size. Your description tells so, you should modify the width and height. If you need to rotate the content, then the + sign will change.

Comment: I actually want the bitmap (= it's an image object) to be rotated I've modified a bit my question, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: If your pivot is a fixed point, after your rotation you would just need to add the original width of the image to the end y-position. Is that what you're trying to achieve? I am not seeing how you could get what you want with just a rotation. Unless you mean to rotate the image while keeping the pivot in the bottom-left corner. In which case you can just change the pivot location after your rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get what you want, because you want to:

- Rotate the image
- Translate the image
- Update the pivot
- Have the inspector read no rotation, no translation, pivot at 0

Each of the first three are mutually exclusive with the fourth.

*At best* you can perform the first three actions, then parent the image to an otherwise empty GameObject that is located on the correct corner and has no rotation applied to it. But it won't be the same object, it'll be a parent object.

Comment: So here's my idea: re-create a new object with the new configuration. I've made a code, I'll hope this will work. The problem is that I'm working 8 hours for my developper's daily job and 5 hours on Unity and it's really hard to mix Python on one side (easy, quick & clean development) with Unity and C# (both really hard to learn environments). I'm sorry for that.